# Best methods to merge 2 Silverlight solutions?

Tags: silverlight, merge, branching-and-merging

I have two branches of a single Silverlight 5 solution.  They are both built off of the same base project.  I will be merging one into the other.  Some files can be simply copied over, while others will need to merged line by line at the code level.

Thoughts as to the best practices for a merging process on such a large scale such as this?

Tools that may be useful?

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me in the past is to check one branch into a source control system. Then point the source control over to the other branch directory and try to check that in. Typically it will find the easy differences to check in and show you the files to merge by hand. I use WinMerge for a file based merge tool since its free. For source control, I wrote my own so I could easily refactor in the large and not fight with source control over it.